# Struggling with Tornado - Celery integration

Tags: celery, tornado

I am in the process of building a Tornado Web server which requires to perform some blocking tasks such as zipping video files, etc which are time consuming. Ideally, I would like to hand off these tasks
to a subprocess utility like Celery and inform the Client accordingly. So, I took [this](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery/tree/master/examples) code from GitHub & modified it to get better understanding. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and here's what I have done so far:

- Installed Tornado and working great on its own.
- Installed RabbitMQ (`apt-get install rabbitmq-server`).
- Installed Tornado Celery (downloaded and unzipped the tar file).
- Executed `python -m pip install tornado-celery`
- Borrowed 2 example python files from above Github Repo and modified it.

My Tasks snippet code (myTornadoTasks.py) is:

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

from celery import Celery
from celery import task

celery = Celery("myTornadoTasks", broker="amqp://")
celery.conf.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND', 'amqp')

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return int(x) + int(y)

    ..... some more code 

@celery.task
def error(msg):
    raise Exception(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   celery.start()
```

I start the tasks using `celery worker -A myTornadoTasks &`. Here everything works fine and I see 24 threads running.

My Tornado Celery snippet code (myTornadoCelery.py) is:

```
from tornado import gen 
from tornado import ioloop 
from tornado.web import asynchronous, RequestHandler, Application

import myTornadoTasks

import tcelery tcelery.setup_nonblocking_producer()

class AsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        myTornadoTasks.sleep.apply_async(args=[3], callback=self.on_result)

    def on_result(self, response):
        self.write(str(response.result))
        self.finish()

... some more code

application = Application([
    (r"/async-sleep", AsyncHandler),
    (r"/gen-async-sleep", GenAsyncHandler),
    (r"/gen-async-sleep-add", GenMultipleAsyncHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8887)
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I start Tornado using `python -m tcelery --app=myTornadoCelery --address=0.0.0.0`

I get an error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'`

Questions:

- What does the above error mean? What am I missing?
- Did I miss any steps here? Where is RabbitMQ invoked?
- How do I increase/decrease the number of Celery workers from 24?

Thanks.

**Updated with Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tcelery/__main__.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tcelery/__main__.py", line 56, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 469, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 489, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 240, in find_app
    found = sym.celery
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

Comment: please show the full traceback

Comment: you can control the number of workers using the [--concurrency](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency) command line parameter

Comment: that's very hard to read - please update your question instead

Comment: ok, updated the question with the error.

Comment: ok, I started my Tornado server by simply doing "python myTornadoCelery.py" and didn't receive any errors. Went to my browser and hit the IP http://localhost:8887/async-sleep. I see the Celery task receive the request on the console, but my browser is now hung. Shouldn't it come back in 3 seconds and display results?

Comment: Can somebody please help me out? Thanks

Comment: if your question no longer accurately describes your problem you should ask a new question - this is not a discussion forum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use Tornado+ Celery+ RabbitMQ + Redis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470741/can-i-use-tornado-celery-rabbitmq-redis)