# How to run Celery worker within a Tornado IO Loop?

Tags: io, celery, tornado

I have a Tornado Websocket server which maintains open connections to multiple websockets (mobile devices). Now there is a queue which has all the messages, which needs to be sent to all the connected websockets. So I am trying to write this program, which consumes messages from the queue and sends them to all the open connections. Here's my code so far:

```
open_websocket_connections = []

class GetDataSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        open_websocket_connections.appped(self)
        logging.info('connection opened')

    def on_close(self):
        open_websocket_connections.remove(self)
        logging.info('connection closed')


def on_message(message, *args, **kwargs):
    for connection in open_websocket_connections:
        connection.write_message(message)

# missing celery code part
def consume_messages(queue, *args, **kwargs):
    # connect to `queue`
    # call `on_message`

# missing ioloop code
# run the `consume_messages` in an ioloop
```

So how do I complete the missing part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use Tornado+ Celery+ RabbitMQ + Redis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470741/can-i-use-tornado-celery-rabbitmq-redis)

Comment: @Louis, I don't think it is. Neither the question nor the only answer I see there talks about running a Celery worker using a Tornado `IOLoop`.

Comment: @russoue The answer does address what you are asking. It does mention the possibility of using `tornado-celery` which does bring in [Tornado's `IOLoop`](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ioloop).

Comment: @Louis `tornado-celery` handles the producer side of it, not the worker side. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @russoue Hmm... I think you're right that it does nothing on the worker side. Retracting close vote.