# Celery worker using event loop

Tags: python, celery, tornado

Does a `Celery` worker use any event loop for e.g. asynchronous I/O and long running tasks? What's the threading model it is using? Is it possible to make it use the `IOLoop` of `Tornado`?

EDIT:

Please note that it is not a duplicate of [Can i use Tornado+ Celery+ RabbitMQ + Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470741/can-i-use-tornado-celery-rabbitmq-redis) because neither the question nor the only answer on it (as of now) talks about running a `Celery` worker with a `Tornado` `IOLoop`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use Tornado+ Celery+ RabbitMQ + Redis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470741/can-i-use-tornado-celery-rabbitmq-redis)

Comment: @Louis, as I noted in a comment in another question, neither the question you pointed to nor the only answer it has now talks about running a Celery worker with a Tornado loop.

Comment: The answer does address what you are asking. It does mention the possibility of using `tornado-celery` which does bring in [Tornado's `IOLoop`](https://github.com/mher/tornado-celery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ioloop).

Comment: `tornado-celery` handles the producer side of it, not the worker side. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is this option:

```
celery worker --help

...

-P POOL_CLS, --pool=POOL_CLS
                    Pool implementation: prefork (default), eventlet,
                    gevent, solo or threads.
```

However documentation is lacking - all the information is [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=pool#concurrency).